# Allowing Underscore in Username Routes in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

Just wondering how I can edit my routes file to allow routing of usernames with an underscore character "_" in them. Here's the relevant code:

```
controller :users do
 match ':id' => :show, :via => :get, :constraints => { :id => /[A-Za-z0-9\-\+]+/ }
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your regular expression to add an `_` as follows:

```
/[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\+]+/
```

The completed `match` will look like this:

```
match ':id' => :show, :via => :get, :constraints => { :id => /[A-Za-z0-9\-\_\+]+/ }
```

Answer (score 2):

The construction `A-Za-z0-9\_` is the same as `\w`. So we can use shorter version:

```
/[\w\-\+]+/
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this regex pattern doesn't ignore this test string:

```
XXXX XXXXX
```

It has space between string.
If you update this regex pattern it will ignore this that test string:

```
controller :users do
  match ':id' => :show, :via => :get, :constraints => { :id => /^[\w\-\+]+$/ }
end
```